# VBA Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take a cell value from one workbook, and find if it occurs in a column on another workbook, returning a "yes" or "no" answer. I thought the best way to do this would be the Intersect command. I'm getting the "method 'range' of object 'global' failed" error.

Any advice would be welcome.

```
' Next part puts a "Yes" or "No" in PHO column
' based on one-at-a-time comparison of new keys in column Y
' against Column C of today's PHO report
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim CurrentPHO As Workbook
Dim TodaysDate As String
Dim PHOCompare As Range
Dim CurrentRow As String
Dim CellCounter As Range

TodaysDate = Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")

Set CurrentPHO = Workbooks.Open("\\netapp02\ProcurementDocs$\PHO\PHO " & TodaysDate & ".xlsx") 'This Opens and defines today's PHO report
Set PHOCompare = CurrentPHO.Worksheets("Detail").Range("C:C")


For RowCount = 2 To LastRow
    Set CellCounter = Workbooks("IBUT 11-4-14.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y" & RowCount)
    If Not Intersect(CellCounter, Range(PHOCompare)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("K" & RowCount).Value = "No"
            Else: Range("K" & RowCount).Value = "Yes"
    End If
Next RowCount
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: `Range(PHOCompare)` hardly makes sense if `PHOCompare` is already a `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim CurrentPHO As Workbook
Dim TodaysDate As String
Dim PHOCompare As Range
Dim CurrentRow As String
Dim CellCounter As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range

TodaysDate = Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")

Set CurrentPHO = Workbooks.Open("\\netapp02\ProcurementDocs$\PHO\PHO " & TodaysDate & ".xlsx") 'This Opens and defines today's PHO report
Set PHOCompare = CurrentPHO.Worksheets("Detail").Range("C:C")


For RowCount = 2 To LastRow
    Set CellCounter = Workbooks("IBUT 11-4-14.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y" & RowCount)

Set FoundCell = PHOCompare.Find(CellCounter.Value)
    Range("K" & RowCount).Value = IIf(IsEmpty(FoundCell), "No", "Yes")
Set FoundCell = Nothing

Next RowCount
```

Comment: I am wondering: Doesn't this code flip the value of ("K" & RowCount) continuously as is finds through column C? Would a Match command work here, so that it only changes the value of ("K" & RowCount) if it finds a match? Then if no match is found declare value "no"?

Comment: Nevermind. I see: It only changes value if "K" AFTER the Find command is complete.

Comment: Just to clarify - your theory is correct with the Match() function, however this method causes VBA to throw an error if a match isn't found - you could of course, incorporate an error handler to test this and deal with it effectively - but I find it simpler to use the find method and test if it was successful with a range object.

Ultimately it's just down to personal preference.